module 'keras_nlp' has no attribute 'models
HAS ANYONE ELSE EXPERIENCED THE SAME ERROR WHEN RUNNING IT LOCALLY? IT RUNS CORRECTLY ON COLAB.
module 'keras_nlp' has no attribute 'models
i

Tried to install the updated version of
pip install -U tensorflow
pip install -U keras 
pip install -U keras-nlp 
